# My button doesn't shows up with its background image's size When i using WRAP_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-button

Here is my `Button`

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.guide_view_image_item, null);
viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
viewHolder.myButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_goto_loginview);
```

Here is `guide_view_image_item.xml` with `btn_goto_loginview` inside

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" >

    </ImageView>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_goto_loginview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/skep_button_in_guide_page"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

skep_button_in_guide_page  is a 182*182 PNG(32-bit color)6.10Kb Image

my program works fine, but the myButton just shows up too big!(my ScreenWidth is 480 and this button's width coverd half of my ScreenWidth)

Then i use

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams myButtonLayout = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.myButton.getLayoutParams();
```

and i find that both `myButtonLayout.width` & `myButtonLayout.height` equals to -2, I think maybe it means WRAP_CONTENT. Then i use

```
BitmapFactory.Options buttonOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
imageOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(EngageApp.getIns().getResources(), R.drawable.skep_button_normal, buttonOptions);
```

Then i find that `buttonOptions.outWidth` & `buttonOptions.outHeight` both equals to 273
so i think it's the actual(real) width which is shown on the screen. 
It's strange, where does 273 comes from? it should be 182..

Finally, I have to use this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams myButtonLayout = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.myButton.getLayoutParams();
myButtonLayout.width = 182;
myButtonLayout.height = 182;
viewHolder.myButton.setLayoutParams(myButtonLayout);
```

enforce set the width&heigth to 182

Then, Everything is ok, myButton got smaller which is my exact purpose.
But I dont think It's the right way to solve this problem.

Anyone can help me?? Thanks in advance.

---

Maybe my description is confusing, Let me make it more clear.

First, My Image is 182 width and i use WRAP_CONTENT, why my button doesn't shows up with 182 width on a 480 width screen directly.

Second, why i got 273 when i using 'decodeResource'? 273 is not the width of the image(182 is,i don't even know where this number comes from), but it is the width that the button is actually showing. Help me explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enforcing it to 182 is wrong but there is nothing wrong with setting the layout params.
it's 182 for the 480 width what if the width changes to 320 or say 720 you should try

```
private void getTheDisplay() {

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        width = dm.widthPixels;
        hieght = dm.heightPixels;
    }



RelativeLayout.LayoutParams myButtonLayout = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.myButton.getLayoutParams();
myButtonLayout.width = ((182*width)/480);  //---got the ratio 182/480 and got the exact width for other screen size as well
myButtonLayout.height = ((182*height)/854);
viewHolder.myButton.setLayoutParams(myButtonLayout);
```

it will scale it up automatically for every screen size

**To Answer your question in comment**

the 273 width come from the pixel to dp conversion this is how it works

Size you see=(actual Size of image * Your screen pixel Density) /160

which in your case is (182*240)/160=273

Comment: But i Still wondering about two things. First, My Image is 182 width and i use WRAP_CONTENT, why my button doesn't shows up with 182 width on a 480 width screen directly. Second, why i got 273 when i using 'decodeResource'? 273 is not the width of the image(182 is,i don't even know where this number comes from), but it is the width that the button is actually showing. I'm really confuse now.

Comment: it is 273 because of the pixel to dp conversion this is how it works

Comment: Sorry, i'm quite new to android, How do you know my screen pixel density is 240? and, where does 160 comes from?

Comment: for the hdpi devices the pixel density is 240 and for the mdpi which is base the pixel density is 160

Comment: run it on mdpi device which has 320*480 resolution the image size will be exactly 182 try running the project on an emulator hvga and you will notice the image size is what you expect

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32399/discussion-between-mera-client-chor-hai-and-triplegg)